# 2 wire rtd pt100 in a wheatstone bridge using ad620

Tags: batteries, pt100

can i use ad620 with rtdp pt100??i already made a schematics in Proteus but it  give me constant voltage 3.7 v.increasing or decreasing temperature didn't effect output voltage at ad620 ..i place a 100 ohm resistor for gain...vs=+5 and -vs=-5 for ad620[image]

Comment: Show the full circuit and how the power supplies interconnect with ground and please put their voltage values on.

Comment: Why does nobody think of turning of the grid when taking the screengrabs? That way we could read the text.

Answer (score 1):

Using 100 ohm as the gain setting resistor gives the AD620 a gain of 495 so with the 0.81 volt offset that you have on the input, your output will try to swing to about 400 volts (which it can't): -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is pin 5, the REF pin. In your application you need to ground it. If you look at [page 12 of the data sheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD620.pdf), you'll see an equivalent schematic which simplifies to

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWwxEm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the REF pin is not connected, you get a circuit which will produce an output like you're getting. If you ground the REF it will act as a differential amp, and this is what you want.

You can also use the REF pin as an offset generator, but that's another story.